# toArray on Stream of String returns Object[]

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have this code :

```
Stream<String> stringStream = Stream.of("a", "b", "c");
Object[] arr = stringStream.toArray();
```

Why is `arr` not a `String[]`?

Comment: Java can't infer a generic type based on the return value of a call.

Comment: Also arrays are weird in that they remember their item type at runtime and check for it. So without `toArray()` knowing what type of array it's supposed to create, it can't create anything but an `Object[]`

Comment: Just use [`toArray(String[]::new)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-)

Comment: @GBlodgett this is about `Stream`s, not `List`s.

Comment: Try to implement `toArray()` method as generic and see if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The toArray function of a Stream naturally returns an `Object[]`.

*This is the signature of the function:*

```
<A> A[] toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)
```

You may notice that there is a **generator** as a parameter.
The purpose of the `IntFunction<A[]> generator` is to convert an integer, the size of the array, to a new array.

To get an `String[]`, you can do this:

```
Stream<String> stringStream = Stream.of("a", "b", "c");
String[] arr = stringStream.toArray(size -> new String[size]);
```

For more information, you can consult the [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray())

Hope this helps!